# Sum values given conditions

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to make a conditional sum of values in a column provided that they share the same Country, Year, and Age and divide the whole sum by a value given by Num. My dataframe looks something like this:

```
Country Num Year Age Variable
AU      20  1989 12  0.009
AU      20  1989 12  0.0015
AU      20  1989 13  0.008
AU      19  1990 19  0.005
USA     1   2011 55  0.0001
```

I have tried so far by using dplyr but I am confused on how to condition effectively and how to divide by Num

```
dta %>% mutate(Variable) %>% group_by(Country,Year,Age) %>% 
 summarise(ME=sum(Variable)[,"ME"], MAE=sum(Variable)[,"MAE"])
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: It's unclear to me what you're trying to achieve. Perhaps you could provide  us with your desired output ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a `dplyr` solution for what (I guessed) you are trying to achieve.

```
dat %>% group_by(Country, Year, Age) %>% mutate(ME = sum(Variable)/sum(Num))
Source: local data frame [5 x 6]
Groups: Country, Year, Age

  Country Num Year Age Variable           ME
1      AU  20 1989  12   0.0090 0.0002625000
2      AU  20 1989  12   0.0015 0.0002625000
3      AU  20 1989  13   0.0080 0.0004000000
4      AU  19 1990  19   0.0050 0.0002631579
5     USA   1 2011  55   0.0001 0.0001000000
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `data.table` you could do this

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dat)[, ME := sum(Variable)/sum(Num), by = .(Country, Year, Age)]

#> dat
#   Country Num Year Age Variable           ME
#1:      AU  20 1989  12   0.0090 0.0002625000
#2:      AU  20 1989  12   0.0015 0.0002625000
#3:      AU  20 1989  13   0.0080 0.0004000000
#4:      AU  19 1990  19   0.0050 0.0002631579
#5:     USA   1 2011  55   0.0001 0.0001000000
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I completely understand what you mean by divide the whole sum by a value given by Num, but here is a simple solution:

```
ddply(dta, c('Country','Year','Age'), function(d) {
  data.frame(wsum = sum(d$Variable)/sum(d$Num))
})
```